# Using in app billing library in a project with eclipse

Tags: android

I am trying to use this library:

https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

I am using eclipse. I downloaded the jar file and copied it to libs folder of my project. When I put this line to my Activity class:

```
implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler
```

I am getting following compiler error:

```
BillingProcessor cannot be resolved to a type
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You can add a jar in Eclipse by right-clicking on the Project → Build Path → Configure Build Path. Under Libraries tab, click Add Jars or Add External JARs and give the Jar.

Comment: I tried it but still same.